# Filling attribute table automatically but with specific values in QGIS 3.10

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table

I'm currently trying to built a database for a cocoa plantation. I would like to know how to fill my database easily with the field calculator. For example I would like to have a specific value for my field `"Varieté"`, but not for all the column.

Is it possible to put the value `"Upala Silva"` only for the `"ID"` 1 to 70?

[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

From Field Calculator, Check `Update existing field`, and select `"Varieté"` field. Then, you can use the following conditional statement in the field calculator:

```
case
when "ID" <= 70 then 'Upala Silva'
when ("ID" > 70  and "ID" <= 100) then 'bbbbb'
.
.
.
else 'ccccc'
end
```

The other conditions are just an example on how to add different ranges. Therefore, you may need to change `"ID" <= 100` to a different value according to your needs. Don't forget to remove the dots if you don't have other conditions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i will try it !

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to ahmadhand's solution you may try using `if`-function.

```py
if("ID" <= 70, 'Upala Silva', '')
```

> *function if*
>
> Tests a condition and returns a different result depending
>   on the conditional check.
>
> *Syntax*
>
> `if(condition,result_when_true,result_when_false)`
>
> Arguments
>
> - `condition` the condition which should be checked
> - `result_when_true` the result which will be returned when the condition is true or > another value that does not convert to false
> - `result_when_false` the result
>     which will be returned when the condition is false or another value
>     that converts to false like 0 or ''. NULL will also be converted to
>     false.

More about **Conditional Functions** you can find [here](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html#conditional-functions).